# Read logs after a particular day?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-file

**BACKGROUND:**

We have `rsyslog` creating log files directories like: `/var/log/rsyslog/SERVER-NAME/LOG-DATE/LOG-FILE-NAME`
So multiple servers are spilling out their logs of different dates to a central location.

Now to read these logs and store them in elasticsearch for analysing I have my logstash config file something like this:

```
file{
   path => /var/log/rsyslog/**/*.log
}
```

**ISSUE:**

Now we want to read log files after a particular date. Eg If in the directory `/var/log/rsyslog` there are logs of April, May, June 2015 and I want to read all logs after a particular date say > `15.05.2015`.

Can this be achieved using logstash `file` input?

**EDIT:**
After reading more I guess it cannot be achieved using `file` input instead I can use `drop` filter to drop logs after a date.

Regex to drop where date > `15.05.2015` ??  How to achieve this using `regex` ??